# Submit the another website submit button from website

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to submit the another website submit button from my website using javascript, is it possible..? My Code are below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formSubmit() {
        document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    }
</script>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="http://XXXXX/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdefault.aspx?" id="form1" >
    <input type="hidden" name="NewCorporateId" id="NewCorporateId" value="XX" />
        <input type="hidden" name="UserName" id="UserName" value="XXXX" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Password" id="Password" value="XXXX"  />
</form>

<form name="form2" id="form2" method="post> 

 <a href ="javascript:formSubmit()">Click here</a>

</form>
```

Comment: What's what that code does. What problem are you encountering?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Look edited code.. I want to submit the another website submit button from my website using javascript

Comment: please rephrase your question and help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: basically, you want to submit this form on another website?

Comment: @Spluf, yes correct..

Comment: well, that's called cross site scripting, you won't get any help here, it's malicious programming. If you really need to, check a course on cross site scripting and ethical hacking.

Comment: Again: What problem are you encountering? If you set the `action` to refer to a different site (as you did originally), the form will be submitted there.

Comment: @Spluf: No, that's not cross-site scripting. It's perfectly fine to submit a form to a different origin.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I have try to submit the button in referring site "http://XXXXX/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdefault.aspx".  Specified URL opened fine in new tab and button not submitted in that site. That site contain the one submit button and username and password text filed.. I have username and password value.. So i try to submit the button in referring site from my website..

Comment: You'll need to have someone help you with your English. Perfect English is **not** required, but we need to be able to understand what you're asking. You keep repeating the same unclear thing, which isn't going to get us anywhere; and you keep not answering the question: What problem are you running into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specified URL opened fine in new tab and button not submitted in that
>   site. That site contain the one submit button and username and
>   password text filed.. I have username and password value.. So i try to
>   submit the button in referring site from my website.

Its possible and **the post code is correct**, **but because you post on aspx page** `Login.aspx`, aspx pages protect from sending data that is not come from the same site by adding a hash code of controls. Also there is the ViewState of the page, and other hidden parameters added by aspx - **so your call will fail**.

Contact with the one that handle the login.aspx page to give you some way to login there - not direct by the page.

related :
  [What is the purpose of __EVENTVALIDATION __VIEWSTATE in aspx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558022/what-is-the-purpose-of-eventvalidation-viewstate-in-aspx)

Comment: If EvenValidation and Viewstate is set to false then it is possible...? but i know it is not secured.

Comment: @bgs Yes its possible, you can also try to send that hidden variables from copy/paste to your form - but if they change will fail - make some test (right click on rendered page and see all the hidden input controls and what they send)