# How to authenticate Ms Crm for JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have created script using Blazemeter.
But it is getting error related to authenticate, Can you please guys help me how to authenticate Ms. Crm Login. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not sufficient to just "record" the test as modern web applications heavily rely on dynamic parameters, for Microsoft technologies based web apps the most common are [ViewState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb386448(v=vs.100)) and [EventValidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558022/what-is-the-purpose-of-eventvalidation-viewstate-in-aspx)

When you're recording the test it just captures the "current" values while the server expects the values to be dynamic so you need to:

1. Extract the dynamic values from the previous responses using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
2. Save them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
3. Replace recorded values with the variables from step 2

See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) for example implementation.

In addition in certain cases application might use external subsystems for authenticating the users, in that case you need to add properly configured [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to your test plan